# Getting Selected to show on the JQuery Menu LI element

Tags: jquery

I am trying this:

```
function initMenu() {
    $("#menu ul").hide();
    $("#menu li a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();
});
```

but it adds `class="selected"` to the `<a>` attribute... how can I add it to the current `<li>` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're clicking the "A" so your class is added to that element.  However it appears you want it added to the parent of your a tag so...

```
$("#menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    });
```

Comment: thank you! on the same not, how would i remove the "selected" from the one that was previously selected? :)

Comment: Depends on whether you want multiple items to be selectable or not.  If not it's easy to just add $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); to your click handler (before your ($(this).parent().addClass('selected'); code)

Answer (score 1):

Use [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
function initMenu() {
        $("#menu ul").hide();
        $("#menu li a").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initMenu();

    });
```

Comment: Thank you Adam! i tried adding  $("#menu li").removeClass('selected'); right before  $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); to clear previously "selected" LI, but now it just blinks yellow aka selected and removed class from all items

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery parent() function to access li:

```
function initMenu() {
    $("#menu ul").hide();
    $("#menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    });
}
```